# How to obtain a ball shaped structuring element?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I can obtain a ball shaped structuring element like so in matlab, but seems like `cv2.getStructuringElement()` does't have the ball shaped approximation. Is there a way to obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MORPH_ELLIPSE`, with the same size for both axis. Check the [OpenCV tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).

This will produce a *ball / circle* shaped element with a diameter of `5`:

```
cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
```

Comment: It seems this will generate a 2D element (i.e. a circle or disk) but not a true 3D ball.

Comment: @spin yes, getStructuringElement returns 2d shapes, and opencv's morphological operations work on 2d only

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`skimage.morphology.ball`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.ball).

From the doc:

```
skimage.morphology.ball(radius, dtype=<class 'numpy.uint8'>)

Generates a ball-shaped footprint.
This is the 3D equivalent of a disk. A pixel is within the neighborhood if the Euclidean distance between it and the origin is no greater than radius.
```